# Modifying copy of list, modifies original

Tags: python-2.7

I thought I understood how Python handles copies of mutables, but I came upon the following behavior.

```
x = [i for i in xrange(5)]
mylist = [x, x]

mylist_copy = mylist[:]

mylist_copy[0].pop()

mylist

Out : [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

So it seems `mylist` was changed despite changes being made only to `mylist_copy`. How can I create a pure copy of `mylist` so that this does not occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you're indeed making a copy, it is a *shallow copy*: `mylist_copy` contains references to the original `x`.

To make a deep copy, use [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy).

Answer (score 1):

This happens not because of any copying errors when making `mylist_copy`, but because `mylist` is made up of two of the same elements.

```
mylist = [x,x] adds two references to the same object (`x`).
```

As a result, `mylist[0].pop()` will have the same outcome:

```
In [70]: x = [i for i in range(5)]

In [71]: mylist = [x,x]

In [72]: mylist
Out[72]: [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]

In [73]: mylist[0].pop()
Out[73]: 4

In [74]: mylist
Out[74]: [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Here's one way to circumvent this issue:

```
In [80]: x = [i for i in range(5)]

In [81]: mylist = [x, x[:]]

In [82]: mylist_copy = mylist[:]

In [83]: mylist_copy[0].pop()
Out[83]: 4

In [84]: mylist
Out[84]: [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```